# Set cell format and style using Optimized Writer in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I've to write a huge Excel file and the [optimized writer](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/optimized.html#optimized-writer) in openpyxl is what I need.

The question is:
is it possibile to set style and format of cells when using optimized writer? Style is not so important (I would only like to highlight column headers), but I need the correct number format for some columns containing currency values.
I saw that `ws.cell()` method is not available when using optimized writer, so how to do it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also look at the [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module which allows writing huge files in [optimised mode](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_memory.html) with [formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_formats.html).

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('file.xlsx', {'constant_memory': True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
...
```

Comment: Thank you for such an awesome module! Are there any performance benchmarks openpyxl with `optimized_write=True` vs xlsxwriter with `constant_memory=True`?

Comment: The [PyExcelerate](https://github.com/whitehat2k9/PyExcelerate) guys have a benchmark in their [README](https://github.com/whitehat2k9/PyExcelerate/blob/master/README.md) for PyExcelerate, XlsxWriter and OpenPyXL.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Pyexcelerate looks promising in terms of speed, but nothing else: no cell formatting, page setup etc. Hope, xlsxwriter will be faster in future versions.

Comment: Thank you, xlsxwriter looks exactly what I need!

Answer (score 7):

As I can't comment, I'll post an update to Dean's answer here:

openpyxl's api (version 2.4.7) has changed slightly so that it should now read:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook( write_only = True )
ws = wb.create_sheet()

from openpyxl.writer.dump_worksheet import WriteOnlyCell
from openpyxl.styles import Font

cell = WriteOnlyCell(ws, value="highlight")
cell.font = Font(name='Courier', size=36)

cols=[]
cols.append(cell)
cols.append("some other value")
ws.append(cols)
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If you are on version 3.0 import WriteOnlyCell as `from openpyxl.cell import WriteOnlyCell`

Answer (score 1):

Quote from docs:

> Those worksheet only have an append() method, it’s not possible to
>   access independent cells directly (through cell() or range()). They
>   are write-only.

When you pass `optimized_write=True` to the `Workbook` constructor, openpyxl will use `DumpWorksheet` class instead of `Worksheet`. `DumpWorksheet` class is very limited in terms of styling and formatting.

But, look at [append](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/src/22d4b2135553f0a26f931e95c6021c4c2302f494/openpyxl/writer/dump_worksheet.py#cl-205) method - it matches the python type of data you pass to excel types. So, see correct cell formats in the result file after running this:

```
import datetime
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook(optimized_write=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()

for irow in xrange(5):
    ws.append([True, datetime.datetime.now(), 'test', 1, 1.25, '=D1+E1'])

wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Speaking about changing the column headers style - just no way to do it using optimized writer.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WriteOnlyCell to do this.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook(optimized_write = True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()
from openpyxl.writer.dump_worksheet import WriteOnlyCell
from openpyxl.styles import Style, Font, PatternFill
cell = WriteOnlyCell(ws, value="highlight")
cell.style = Style(font=Font(name='Courier', size=36), fill=PatternFill(fill_type='solid',start_color='8557e5'))
cols=[]
cols.append(cell)
cols.append("some other value")
ws.append(cols)
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

I hope this helps.  You can use anything that the style will allow before appending it to the row for the worksheet.